# Cannot read property 'compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync' of undefined: Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create dynamic component and get the reference of DOM object-

this method is used to create the component factory-

```
createComponentFactory(template: string): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    @Component({
        selector: 'dynamic-template',
        template: template
    })
    class DynamicComponent { }

    @NgModule({
        imports: [CommonModule],
        declarations: [DynamicComponent]
    })
    class DynamicModule { }

    return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicModule)
        .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
            return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicComponent);
        });
}
```

following method is used to get DOM reference-

```
getRootNodeFromParsedComponent(template: string): Promise<HTMLElement> {
    if (this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    return this.createComponentFactory(template)
        .then(factory => {
            const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
            this.cmpRef = factory.create(injector);
            const hostView = <EmbeddedViewRef<any>>this.cmpRef.hostView;
            return hostView.rootNodes[0];
        });
}
```

and I'm calling these method using-

```
this.getRootNodeFromParsedComponent('<h1>Dynamic Template Reference Example</h1>').then((elem: HTMLElement) => {
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
});
```

**Problem**

I am getting the output when I'm putting these method inside the class which has Component and Directive decorator but my requirement is I have to put these method inside normal class which has no decorator at all, when I'm doing so I get error-

> Cannot read property 'compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync' of undefined

So, my question is, can I create dynamic component inside the normal class which has no decorator at all.

Comment: Can you add plunker? this.compiler is undefined

Comment: @yurzui thank you for response, plz see plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xakgE4C5KrAi2Seq0rhz?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pwyvJO8CL9iwiuXO6ncC?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thnx you, can we perform two way binding in this example?, please check my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xakgE4C5KrAi2Seq0rhz?p=preview

Comment: There you have to register changeDetector on ApplicationRef. But you can also pass vcRef and then change detection should work https://plnkr.co/edit/tKEWWoBWNneY70tkaZ9U?p=preview

Comment: In 2.3.0, `attachView` was introduced which allows you to be able to attach change detection to the `ApplicationRef`

Comment: @yurzui Can I use all functionality of existing component inside newly dynamically  created component. Can you please look my question here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036639/use-all-behavior-of-component-inside-dynamically-created-component?noredirect=1#comment71248038_42036639