# Use all behavior of Component inside Dynamically Created Component

Tags: angular

I have requirement to create dynamic component or template and get the dom object and append to view container reference. I have created plunker of this which is working fine.

Following is code to create dynamic component-

```
 getDOMElementOfDynamicTemplate( template: string, vcRef: ViewContainerRef ) {

    const html = template;
    if (!html) return;

    if (this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    const compMetadata = new Component({
        template: html
    });
    let factory = this.createComponentFactory( this.compiler, compMetadata );
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders( [], vcRef.parentInjector );
    this.cmpRef = vcRef.createComponent( factory, vcRef.length, injector );
    const hostView = <EmbeddedViewRef<any>>this.cmpRef.hostView;
    return hostView.rootNodes[0];

}

createComponentFactory( compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component ) {
    @Component(metadata)
    class DynamicComponent {
    };
    @NgModule({
        imports: [ CommonModule, FormsModule ],
        declarations: [ DynamicComponent ]
    })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }
    let moduleWithComponentFactory = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync( DynamicHtmlModule )
    return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find( x => x.componentType === DynamicComponent );
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OcKw6EO8zo5Yd5XAQfNb?p=preview)

I want to use same behavior of component inside dynamically created component. As you can see in example I have created clicked() method inside app component and trying to call it from dynamically created component. Can any one suggest me how to do? Is I am following good approach or some alternate approach is there?

Comment: What is the question : click function is not being called or you want to call click function from newly created component?????  existing click has nothing to do with newly created dynamic component.If you create component dynamically, you have to create and compile angular context with it only.

Comment: yes, I want to call click function from dynamically created component and use all behavior of existing component into newly created dynamic component

Comment: I don't think so there is a way to call click fun written in existing component and call it from a newly created component.

Comment: have you tried to move click fun in newly created component? If you do so, click will work for sure. (don't know whether you want that or not though)

Comment: yes, if I move click fun inside newly created component, it's calling but that's not I want. I want to use all functionality of existing component inside newly created component

Comment: @micronyks Is there any other way to create dynamic template and use all behavior of existing component?

Comment: Not getting what are you saying?

Comment: @micronyks, I have requirement to create dynamic DOM element and append it to template. Is there any other way to do this in A2?

Comment: If angular context is there in the element, you have to go with dymanic creation only. Still there are ways to deal with parent and newly injected components but in your case its a sibling component so dont know how to communicate.

Comment: Can u guide me how to do this using parent and newly injected components?

Comment: You can use `EventEmitter` with `output` api to call parent methods from newly injected component which should act as a child of the parent.